# Linked lists in practice

Tags: memory, data-structures, linked-list, storage, ram

I have some questions about the ideas proposed in [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP05i5bU_6I&list=PLCiOXwirraUClSdjZJ6YNwKXQDomG35kf&index=9)

The speaker shows an array that holds values and pointers, and he also shows a separate "free" linked list, that is updated whenever an item is added/removed.

Why are these used? Doesn't using an array / limiting yourself to a set of free nodes defeat the purpose of a linked list?

Isn't one of the perk of using a linked list the ability to traverse fragmented data?

Why use these free nodes, when you can dynamically allocate storage?

The proposed structure, to me, doesn't seem dynamic at all, and is in fact a convoluted and inefficient array.

Comment: Can you include relevant screenshots or quotes from the video? Spending 10 minutes watching a video is a bit too much to expect to fully understand the question (not to mention needing to visit offsite resources, which can be an issue for various reasons).

Comment: Somewhat speculative without full context, but if you're using an array (which could possibly just be RAM) as a linked-list (with elements at arbitrary positions), you can efficiently (in O(1)) remove and insert elements at any index (if you have a reference to the relevant node). You can't do that with a normal array.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you mention makes sense in certain use cases.  For example if the common case is that the array is 90% full and most of the time is spent iterating over it, you can  very quickly loop over an array and just skip the few empty items.  This can be much, much faster than "pointer chasing" which plain linked lists use, because the CPU's hardware prefetcher can predict which memory you will need in advance.

And compared with a plain array and no free list, it has the advantage of O(1) allocation of an element into an empty slot.